# Pygame Drawing a Rectangle

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles, 2d-games

I'm making a game that requires knowing how to draw a rectangle in Python (3.2).

I have checked lot of sources but none show exactly how to do it.

Comment: What are you using for graphics.

Comment: Manual: [pygame.draw.rect](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect)

Comment: Free PDF: [Making Games with Python & Pygame](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/)

Answer (score 29):

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    pygame.init()

    DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)

    WHITE=(255,255,255)
    BLUE=(0,0,255)

    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE,(200,150,100,50))

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

This creates a simple window 500 pixels by 400 pixels that is white. Within the window will be a blue rectangle. You need to use the `pygame.draw.rect` to go about this, and you add the `DISPLAY` constant to add it to the screen, the variable blue to make it blue (blue is a tuple that values which equate to blue in the RGB values and it's coordinates.

Look up [pygame.org](https://www.pygame.org) for more info

Answer (score 14):

here's how:

```
import pygame
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
red=255
blue=0
green=0
left=50
top=50
width=90
height=90
filled=0
pygame.draw.rect(screen, [red, blue, green], [left, top, width, height], filled)
pygame.display.flip()
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this:

[PyGame Drawing Basics](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs5nm/topics/pygame/drawing/)

Taken from the site:

> pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,width,height), thickness) draws a rectangle (x,y,width,height) is a Python tuple x,y are the coordinates of the upper left hand corner width, height are the width and height of the rectangle thickness is the thickness of the line. If it is zero, the rectangle is filled

Answer (score 5):

With the module [pygame.draw](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) shapes like rectangles, circles, polygons, liens, ellipses or arcs can be drawn. Some examples:

[`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) draws filled rectangular shapes or outlines. The arguments are the target *Surface* (i.s. the display), the *color*, the *rectangle* and the optional outline *width*. The *rectangle* argument is a tuple with the 4 components (*x*, *y*, *width*, *height*), where (*x*, *y*) is the upper left point of the rectangle. Alternatively, the argument can be a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(window, color, (x, y, width, height))
```

```py
rectangle = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
pygame.draw.rect(window, color, rectangle)
```

[`pygame.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) draws filled circles or outlines. The arguments are the target *Surface* (i.s. the display), the *color*, the *center*, the *radius* and the optional outline *width*. The *center* argument is a tuple with the 2 components (*x*, *y*):

```py
pygame.draw.circle(window, color, (x, y), radius)
```

[`pygame.draw.polygon`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.polygon) draws filled polygons or contours. The arguments are the target *Surface* (i.s. the display), the *color*, a list of *points* and the optional contour *width*. Each *point* is a tuple with the 2 components (*x*, *y*):

```cpp
pygame.draw.polygon(window, color, [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)])
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Shapes](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Shapes#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 255), (20, 20, 160, 160))
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (100, 100), 80)
    pygame.draw.polygon(window, (255, 255, 0), 
        [(100, 20), (100 + 0.8660 * 80, 140), (100 - 0.8660 * 80, 140)])

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum work would be:

```
# Importing the library
import pygame

# Initializing Pygame
pygame.init()

# Initializing surface
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))

# Initializing color
color = (255,0,0)

# Drawing Rectangle
pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))
pygame.display.flip()
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-rectangle-in-pygame/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to use `pygame.draw.rect()`:

```
pygame.draw.rect(surface/screen, color, [x,y,width,height])
```

Then just remember to update the display.