# What is the difference between pygame.draw.rect and screen_surface.blit()?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a red rectangle move to the right and by using pygame.move.rect or .blit, I   Am able to accomplish the same thing. I am able to display the red rectangle and move it to the right by pressing the right arrow. However, is there any difference between these 2 functions that I should know? Why are there 2 functions that basically do the same thing.

Code with pygame.move.rect

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
#obtain the surface and rect for screen
screen_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hi")

#Obtain Surface and rect for the rectangle 
red_rectangle = pygame.Surface((600,400))
red_rectangle_rect = red_rectangle.get_rect()

#make the rectangle surface red
red_rectangle.fill((255,0,0))

move_right = False

while True:
   #event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            print(event.type)
            print(event.key)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
          

    #rectangle move to right when right arrow is pressed 
    if move_right:
        red_rectangle_rect.x += 10
        print(red_rectangle_rect.x)
        
                
 


    screen_surface.fill((255,255,255))
    
    # the difference between this function and the .blit
    pygame.draw.rect(screen_surface,(255,0,0),red_rectangle_rect)
   

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Code with .blit

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
#obtain the surface and rect for screen
screen_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hi")

#Obtain Surface and rect for the rectangle 
red_rectangle = pygame.Surface((600,400))
red_rectangle_rect = red_rectangle.get_rect()

#make the rectangle surface red
red_rectangle.fill((255,0,0))

move_right = False

while True:
   #event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            print(event.type)
            print(event.key)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
          

    #rectangle move to right when right arrow is pressed 
    if move_right: then 
        red_rectangle_rect.x += 10
        print(red_rectangle_rect.x)
        
                
 


    screen_surface.fill((255,255,255))

 
    #Difference between this and the draw function
    screen_surface.blit(red_rectangle,red_rectangle_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 5):

> Why are there 2 functions that basically do the same thing.

No, they do not the same thing. While [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) draw uniform colored rectangles, [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is a method of [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and is used to draw bitmap images.

See [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect):

> `rect(surface, color, rect) -> Rect`
> Draws a rectangle on the given surface.

See [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)

> `blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect`
> Draws a source Surface onto this Surface

In your case, it looks like they're doing the same thing because your *Surface* object is evenly filled with one color.
The behavior changes completely when you load a bitmap image with [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load). You cannot draw an image using `pygame.draw.rect`, but you can use `blit`.

When to use `pygame.draw.rect`, see:

[Pygame Drawing a Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780411/pygame-drawing-a-rectangle)

When to use `blit`, see:

[What is a good way to draw images using pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/what-is-a-good-way-to-draw-images-using-pygame/64630591#64630591)

Answer (score 2):

**blit(image, (left, top))** - Draws  image to the screen at the given position.The function accepts either a Surface or a string as its image parameter. If image is a str then the named image will be loaded from the images/ directory.

**draw.rect(rect, (r, g, b))** - Draws the outline of a rectangle. Takes a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

So just to clarify,

Use blit for image and rect for rectangle with 1 colour.